# How to use Page property available in ComponentPresentation

Tags: 2013, content-delivery

The ComponentPresentation embeded in the page like this while we publish the page

```
<tridion:ComponentPresentation runat="server" PageURI="tcm:1025-5948-64" ComponentURI="tcm:1025-5430" TemplateURI="tcm:1025-5432-32"/>
```

The ComponentPresentation has a Page property i want to use this page property inside my ComponentPresentation code(user control published by cms) so that i can  get component link by passing pageid in GetLink method.

Comment: from your question it sounds like you are confusing the CM and Delivery side (but that might just be my misunderstanding), can you edit your question and add some more detail in there, like where you are using this code and what `ComponentPresentation` class you are referring to?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you are asking...The Page property is a System.Web.UI.Page object that represents the ASP.NET page that hosts the tridion:ComponentPresentation control.

This is not a property that you should use when calling GetLink method.

You can use the PageURI property though.

Comment: yes i want to know how to access PageURI Property

Comment: You could search for that tridion control using the Controls collection of your page, cast the return to the Tridion.ContentDelivery.Web.UI.ComponentPresentation object. But this does sound like a hack so based on your requirement, there must be something more decent to do from the CM side.